# Split interfaces for OR and exit traffic

Tags: configuration, exit-relays

I'm failing to find a simple way to configure tor to use a different IP for outbound OR traffic and a different one as an exit node.

Unless I'm mistaken `OutboundBindAddress` sets both of them. Did I miss some other relevant option?

Comment: Try using `ORPort` and other 'ports' with a full IP address notations. A corresponding firewall profile would be a great addition to such a setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the source I found the answer. `OutboundBindAddress` controls the source for both the OR and the exit traffic. There's no way to separate the traffic in the official `tor` as of Oct 2016.